# Performing FULLTEXT search after JOIN operation in sequelize

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I have two tables Category and Events and I want to perform a FULLTEXT search on the columns Events.Name,Description,Society and Category.Name after performing a join operation on both the tables in sequelize.
The modals have been defined as follows:
Events.js

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
   module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
     var Events = sequelize.define("Events", {        //Must be same as table name
       Id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         primaryKey: true,
         autoIncrement: true // Automatically gets converted to SERIAL for postgres
       },
       Name: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       Description: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       Venue: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       StartTime: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       EndTime: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       StartDate: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       EndDate: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       CurrentRound: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       Society: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       CategoryId: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         notNull: true
       },
       MaxContestants: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         notNull: true
       },
       Status: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       },
       Pdf: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         notNull: true
       }
     }, {
       timestamps: false,
       tableName: 'Events',
       freezeTableName: true
     }, {
       indexes: [
         { type: 'FULLTEXT', fields: 'name' }
       ]
     },{
       classMethods: {
         associate: function(models) {
           Events.belongsTo(models.Category);
         }
       }
     });
     return Events;
   };
}());
```

Category.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Category = sequelize.define("Category", {
    Id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true // Automatically gets converted to SERIAL for postgres
    },
    Name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'Category',
    freezeTableName: true
  },{
    Indexes: [
      { type: 'FULLTEXT', fields: ['Name'] }
    ]
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Category.hasMany(models.Events);
      }
    }
  });
  return Category;
};
```

The query I am performing is :

```
Model.Events.findAll({
      include: [{ model: Model.Category }],having: ['MATCH(Events.Name,Description,Society,Category.Name) AGAINST(?)', query]   }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      r.status = statusCodes.SUCCESS;
      r.data = JSON.stringify(data);
      return res.end(r.toString());
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
      r.status = statusCodes.SERVER_ERROR;
      r.data = err;
      return res.end(r.toString());
    });
```

The errors I am getting are :

1. FULLTEXT index does not exits.
2. Incorrect arguments to the match.
3. I am not sure if a foreign key has been created.

Please help me out by correcting my query.